# Can I uniquely identify a device in Windows 10/Windows 8/WinRT

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

Is there any mechanism to identify a device uniquely (even if it is anonymous)?

To be clear, by "device" I mean the computer/slate/pc.

**Windows 8.x**

> http://codepaste.net/ybt893

```
string HardwareId()
{
    var token = Windows.System.Profile.HardwareIdentification.GetPackageSpecificToken(null);
    var hardwareId = token.Id;
    var dataReader = Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader.FromBuffer(hardwareId);
    var bytes = new byte[hardwareId.Length];
    dataReader.ReadBytes(bytes);
    return BitConverter.ToString(bytes);
}
```

**Windows 10**

> You must add the Mobile and/or Desktop extension SDK.

```
string HardwareId()
{
    var token = HardwareIdentification.GetPackageSpecificToken(null);
    var hardwareId = token.Id;
    var dataReader = Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader.FromBuffer(hardwareId);
    var bytes = new byte[hardwareId.Length];
    dataReader.ReadBytes(bytes);
    return BitConverter.ToString(bytes);
}
```

Comment: If my application wanted to track sync deltas across devices, for example. (in case you wanted a plausable use case)

Comment: The answer is yes, but not yet (in RC)

Comment: If you use the "GetPackageSpecificToken" API, be very wary of "Accounting for hardware drift" - See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj553431

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Such an ability has just been added in Windows 8 RTM:

```
Windows.System.Profile.HardwareIdentification.GetPackageSpecificToken(null)
```

Comment: If you use this, be very wary of "Accounting for hardware drift" - See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj553431

Answer (score 6):

There doesn't seem to be a convenient way for Metro Style apps in Windows 8 to obtain a system-maintained unique identifier, like Windows Phone 7 provided with its `Microsoft.Phone.Info.DeviceExtendedProperties.GetValue( "DeviceUniqueId" )`

- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-HK/winappswithcsharp/thread/62ac2a48-be60-465c-b3b7-bbb736a67a60
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-NZ/winappswithcsharp/thread/2ca0d5de-9db5-4349-839c-e01ff614ec6e

The best solution I've found so far is to simply generate a [new guid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid.aspx) in [application local storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localsettings.aspx#Y0) and use that identifier to identify the computer for the current and future launches of your app.

```
var localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
Object value = localSettings.Values["uniqueDeviceId"];
if (!value)
{
    value = Guid.NewGuid();
    localSettings.Values["uniqueDeviceId"] = value;
}
```

Keep in mind that the user could delete the local storage and cause your app to forget and regenerate that value (or potentially even modify/spoof the value), so don't depend on it for any critical security purposes.  Since I'm only using this technique for rough statistics and usage reporting, this is fine for my needs.

Comment: A GUID will almost certainly be unique, this is exactly the solution I would propose.

Comment: is this value different if you use another app on the same device?

Comment: The biggest problem with this approach is that if your app gets uninstalled and re-installed you cannot reproduce this Guid to identify the device.

Answer (score 5):

Could this be used as a consistent ID for the logged in user?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.exchangeactivesyncprovisioning.easclientdeviceinformation.id.aspx

***EasClientDeviceInformation.Id | id property***

*Returns the identifier of the local computer. The Id property represents the DeviceId using the GUID truncated from the first 16 bytes of the SHA256 hash of MachineID, User SID, and App ID where the MachineID uses the SID of the local users group. Each component of the GUID is returned in network byte order.*

Comment: Hi, Did you guys find this as a suitable solution? I am evaluating this method for my app.

Comment: this value changes when changing the app